# Left justify pandas string column with pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataset with a messy string column which contains for example:

```
72.1

61

25.73.20

33.12
```

I'd like to fill the gaps in order to match a pattern like XX.XX.XX (X are only numbers):

```
72.10.00

61.00.00

25.73.20

33.12.00
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining `base_string = '00.00.00'` then fill other string in each row with base_string:

```
base_str = '00.00.00'
df = pd.DataFrame({'ms_str':['72.1','61','25.73.20','33.12']})
print(df)

df['ms_str'] = df['ms_str'].apply(lambda x: x+base_str[len(x):])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ms_str
0      72.1
1        61
2  25.73.20
3     33.12


     ms_str
0  72.10.00
1  61.00.00
2  25.73.20
3  33.12.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution, that works for this particular pattern. First fill with zeros on the right, then replace every third character by a dot:

```
df['col'].str.ljust(8, fillchar='0').str.replace(r'(..).', r'\1.', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    72.10.00
1    61.00.00
2    25.73.20
3    33.12.00
Name: col, dtype: object
```